# onLost focus Event is not working -ms access

Tags: ms-access

This code is not working. Can anyone help me out?

```
Private Sub txtErrorComment_5_LostFocus()

    If IsEmpty(Me.txtErrorComment_5) Then
        MsgBox "Eh..! It cannot be Empty."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: "Empty" is a special value in VB(A) for uninitialized variables of the Variant type. It doesn't mean what you'd think it does.

Comment: LostFocus is the wrong event for this. You should be using BeforeUpdate, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

txtErrorComment_5 is probably Null - which evaluates to False when run through IsEmpty() - yes, this is un-intuitive, but whenever you compare to Null, the result is false.

Try the following:

```
Private Sub txtErrorComment_5_LostFocus()

    If IsEmpty(Me.txtErrorComment_5) or IsNull(Me.txtErrorComment_5) Then
        MsgBox "Eh..! It cannot be Empty."
    End If

End Sub
```

Or just:

```
Private Sub txtErrorComment_5_LostFocus()

    If IsNull(Me.txtErrorComment_5) Then
        MsgBox "Eh..! It cannot be Empty."
    End If

End Sub
```

IsNull can handle Null's

**Edit:**

@David-W-Fenton is correct. The better way to do this BeforeUpdate (not LostFocus)

```
Private Sub txtErrorComment_5_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

     If IsNull(Me.txtErrorComment_5) Then
         MsgBox "Eh..! It cannot be Empty."
         Cancel=true
     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I already tried this, did not work either. Actually in my form when a checkbox is filled this textbox should be filled that is the condition. Is there any other way to implement this logic??

Comment: IsEmpty() will never return useful information from a control. It is only of value with a variable of Variant data type.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: but the control's default property is of Variant type.  In the analogous context in Excel, you use IsEmpty() to check for an unedited cell; in Access you use IsNull().  The OP was not as far off the mark as your comment implies.

Comment: My earlier comment seems incomplete.  Empty is a variant that has been initialized to zero (VarType=0).  Null is a variant whose VarType is 1.  The intended meaning is different.  When you declare a variant in VBA, it is initialized to Empty.  Excel cells are also initialized to Empty.  Access controls (those supporting a Value property) are initialized to Null.  The IsNull and IsEmpty functions returns true if the argument's VarType is, respectively 1 or 0.

Comment: The default property of a control is a string value -- if unassigned it's a zero-length string. So, no, it's not a Variant at all. The informationa about Excel also seems to be in error -- when I check Excel help for IsEmpty()_ it's exactly the same function as in Access VBA. I can't find any spreadsheet function (as opposed to VBA function) with that name, either (or anything with "empty" in it).

Answer (score 1):

To detect whether txtErrorComment_5 is blank, concatenate a Null string to its value and see whether the character length of the combined expression is zero.

```
Private Sub txtErrorComment_5_LostFocus()
    If Len(Me.txtErrorComment_5 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Eh..! It cannot be Empty."
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want txtErrorComment_5 treated as blank when it contains only one or more space characters, include the Trim() function.

```
Private Sub txtErrorComment_5_LostFocus()
    If Len(Trim(Me.txtErrorComment_5) & vbNullString) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Eh..! It cannot be Empty."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This technique is fairly verbose.  If you need to check for both null and zero-length strings, I'd suggest writing a simple IsNullOrEmpty() function.  however, by default, Access doesn't allow zero-length strings, so the built in IsNull() function is usually adequate.

Comment: @phoog In both Access 2003 and 2007 when I create a new Text field, the Allow Zero Length property is Yes.  If there is a way to change that behavior, please share.  I would much prefer not to have to change that property to No for each new Text field.  Thanks.

Comment: Weird. Perhaps my memory is faulty? It's been a while since I've created an Access table for production work, so I haven't paid much attention.  The computer I'm using now doesn't have Access.  I'll try to check it out the next time I'm on a computer that does.